# Defining the type of simultaneously retrospective and prospective cohort study

Tags: medicine, experiment-design

I'm planning a study design that starts collecting patients from 2015 to 2021, but as a three-year follow-up is necessary, their outcome measures will be recorded up to 2024. Thus, how should I define the type of this study? Does retrospective seem the most wrong? Just "cohort study"? Or "prospective"?

Comment: There is a little-used term for this type of study design. If you are including data from the past, the common term is "retrospective". If you're including data from the future, the common term is "prospective". If you are including both types of data, the term in epidemiology is AMBISPECTIVE. I think it was coined by Mosteller, but I can't be sure. Personally, I hate the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that you are describing a [longitudinal study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study). Normally that assumes that the same subjects will be studied over time, so you may have a variation on the basic idea depending on your design.